# sql query that not show all records

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a problem with a query, for example with this one i can retrieve the records:

```
SELECT 
l.*, 
ll.f_cocacola as cocacola, 
 le.name AS deposit, 
 lp.price
FROM 
 KPC AS l, 
 KPC_cocacola AS ll, 
 KPC_deposit AS le, 
 KPC_price AS lp 
WHERE 
l.cod_deposit = le.id_deposit 
AND l.code = ll.code
AND lp.code = l.code
AND l.code_deposit = '002365'
```

but now i need to include another date from another table -intranet- that has the fields *code* and *url* then need to show from this table the *url* field .. keep in mind that the relationship is on the *code* field.

so i change the query in this way:

```
SELECT l.*,ll.f_cocacola as cocacola, le.name AS deposit, 
lp.price, lintranet.url 
FROM tableX AS l, intranet_cocacola AS ll, tableX_deposit AS le, 
tableX_price AS lp, 
tableX_intranet as lintranet 
WHERE l.code_deposit = le.id_deposit
AND l.code = ll.code
AND lp.code = l.code 
AND l.code = lintranet.code
AND l.code_deposit = '456852147'
```

but the issue is that some records don't have a *url* and if is not exist a *url* then this query don't show me the record .. well what i need that even if there is not a *url* associated to a record i want to see that recorda, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your query using ANSI join syntax and use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  l.*, ll.f_cocacola as cocacola, le.name AS deposit, 
        lp.price, lintranet.url 
FROM    tableX AS l,
JOIN    intranet_cocacola AS ll
ON      ll.code = l.code
JOIN    tableX_deposit AS le
ON      le.id_deposit = l.code_deposit
JOIN    tableX_price AS lp
ON      lp.code = l.code
LEFT JOIN
        tableX_intranet as lintranet
ON      lintranet.code = l.code
WHERE   l.code_deposit = '456852147'
```

Comment: your answer is pretty more clear and i chose this one and i upvote also the @zerkms answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT l.*,ll.f_cocacola as cocacola, le.name AS deposit, 
lp.price, lintranet.url 
FROM tableX AS l, intranet_cocacola AS ll, tableX_deposit AS le, 
tableX_price AS lp
LEFT JOIN tableX_intranet as lintranet ON l.code = lintranet.code -- <<<<<
WHERE l.code_deposit = le.id_deposit
AND l.code = ll.code
AND lp.code = l.code 
AND l.code_deposit = '456852147'
```

PS: personally I prefer explicit `INNER JOIN`, rather than join using comma separated tables enumeration. Because it gives better picture of what the query does

Comment: both answers are very good., and now i don't know what i can choose for good reputation of you and Quassnoi :(

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already have an answer, but I see your question was made over Oracle database... while I think LEFT JOIN works because it's standar SQL, Oracle has it's own version, so you can see this same query written as follows:

```
SELECT l.*,ll.f_cocacola as cocacola, le.name AS deposit, lp.price, lintranet.url 
  FROM tableX AS l, intranet_cocacola AS ll, tableX_deposit AS le, tableX_price AS lp, tableX_intranet as lintranet
 WHERE l.code_deposit = le.id_deposit
   AND l.code = ll.code
   AND lp.code = l.code 
   AND l.code_deposit = '456852147'
   AND l.code = lintranet.code(+)  //<-- this is how a left/right join is written
                                   //on Oracle's SQL, you add "(+)" next to the 
                                   //field of the table that may not have 
                                   //matching records.
```

Comment: thank you, i also up vote your answer, is good one .. good night

Comment: This syntax is deprecated in `9i` and above

Comment: @Quassnoi really? didn't know that... tough, I liked it better!